# Decoupled Message Queue Pattern for Login

Tags: message-queue, decoupling

Let's say a user accesses a resource and it maps to a handler foo().

In foo() I want to check if the user's session is valid.
For maximum decoupling (and for the sake of the example) I put the provided session ID into a message and push that into the queue VERIFY_SESSION where it is picked up by a subscribed worker.
The worker takes the session ID out of the message, checks the database, etc and then adds some data indicating the session is valid to the message before pushing it to VERIFIED_SESSIONS.

**Question**:
How do I get the information that the session is valid back into the worker that handles the user's connection?

If I subscribe all frontend workers to the queue VERIFIED_SESSIONS, there is no way of telling which worker will receive it.
All I can think of would be to basically implement RPC on top of the message queue, but that would defeat the purpose of having the queue to begin with.

What is the common pattern here?

Comment: Why does it matter which worker recieves it?

Comment: Because one worker handles the connection of the user. Let's say there's frontend worker A and B. The user connects to to /foobar and the loadbalancer sends him to A. While A dispatches the verifySession message, the TCP connection stays open as the user has not yet received a response. When the session is verified, the outcome must thus somehow get back to frontend worker A as it has access to the TCP connection and must send a response to the user. Worker B could do so in theory but may well be in a different location and has no access to the TCP connection.